# What does 上 mean as in 抱歉我没帮上忙?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I could roughly understand the meaning of the sentence.

> Sorry, I didn't help much.

By the simple Chinese-English dictionary, 上 means

```
up
get on
good
superior
```

There are tons of meanings by the advanced dictionary. I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should translate like this:

Sorry 抱歉

I 我

wasn't 没

able 上

to

help 帮忙

Answer (score 3):

上 denotes this sense:

> （用在动词后， 表示动作的结果）(Used after a verb to indicate its result)  E.g. 穿上外衣; 考上大学

我没帮上忙 means (*the result is that) I have been being helpless.*. It's not a word for word translation though.

Answer (score 2):

**上** functions here as a resultative complement, just like the second character in 做**完** or 吃**好**.

Consider the difference in English between *"I have not helped you"* and *"I have not managed to help you."* `managed`, here, appears with the meaning of `"could"` or `"succeeded"`. Think of `上` in the same way in this case.

Answer (score 1):

it carries the same meaning as the out in "sorry,I wasnt able to help out"

Out by itself does not mean much, but couple with help, it reinforced the help word